# A category object in an $\infty$-category

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am quite confused on what a category object in an $(\infty,1)$ category [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+object+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category).

[image]

> How did we get the diagram
>
> $$X(\{0,1\}) \times \cdots  \times X(\{n-1,n\})$$
> in the first place ?

If we were to spell out the definition of an $(\infty, 1)$-limit, we would want a simplicial set $K$, and a morphism $p:K \rightarrow C$ that gives the diagram written above.

---

I am guessing the definition should be that we take $K$ as the nerve of
$$ \{0 \} \rightarrow \{0,1\} \leftarrow \cdots \rightarrow \{n-1,n\} \leftarrow \{n \}$$
which maps in to $\Delta$ by sending one element set to $[0]$ and two element sets to $[1]$. Then there is a canonical
$K \rightarrow K^{\triangleleft} \rightarrow C$ that extends our diagram via the sending the cone point to $[n]$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: The definition of limity in an $\infty$-category of shape $K$, is given by a morphism $p:K \rightarrow C$, and an extenstion $p:K^{\triangleleft} \rightarrow C$. What is the $K$ here? @asdq, is this clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the diagram in definition 2.2 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Segal+condition).

Comment: So it's what I wrote in my last edit? I got the arrows in the wrong direction though. Let me edit it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not see your edit before writing my answer.